# Using Blackberry MDS Simulator for connecting to specific SSID

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde, mds-cs

I'm trying to create a Blackberry app that will connect to a specific SSID, but the Blackberry MDS Simulator only provides a 'Default WLAN Test Network' - is there any way to change the SSID of the WLAN the MDS Simulator creates?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.

> **Note:** this doesn't actually require the **MDS (BES)** simulator.  The MDS simulator simulates MDS.  WiFi is a *different* transport, and is
>   supported directly in the **device** simulators (e.g. 8900, 9900,
>   etc.).  So, you only really need the device simulator running for
>   this.

- From the device simulator menu, select **Simulate -> Network Properties**.
- Then, select the **Add...** button.
- Select the `WLAN` network type, and then give your new WiFi network the SSID (Name) you want.
- Make sure then that in the **Network Properties** window, your new WiFi network has **In Coverage** checked, and the Signal Strength should be turned up (e.g. -40 dBm).  You might also choose to disable the `Default WLAN Network` by unchecking the **In Coverage** box for it, so you can be sure your new network is the one being used.
- Then, you use the BlackBerry simulator like a normal device to connect to the new network:
- Select the **Manage Connections** button, then **Set Up Wi-Fi Network**.  Follow the instructions, and select the **Scan for Networks** button.

You should now have a working Wi-Fi network.

---

I believe you can also look in the *.conf files that are normally stored in your `%PROFILE%` directory (e.g. C:\Users\username) under `.\net\rim\fledge-2`.   They should contain properties for the saved Wi-Fi networks for your simulator(s).

[More info here](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/connecting_the_bbsmrtphnsmltr_to_bes_mds_smltr_607564_11.html)